# Groupby or pivot to sum by category in date range

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm quite new to pandas and I'm try to solve the following problem.
My database that looks like this:

[image: example table]

and I need to basically find out who sold the most between 2017 and 2018 (largest change between the two dates and by which type of fruit)

sorry if it's a silly question, but I really can't find a simple solution using either groupby or pivot.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.pivot_table` is a good choice:

```
dfp = df.pivot_table(index=[ 'country', 'fruits'], columns=['date'],
                     values='kgsold', aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)

# date            2017  2018
# country fruits            
# germany apples     1     2
#         figs       0     3
#         pears      5     1
# italy   apples    10     5
#         pears      0    13
```

You can then query the pivot table with your requirements.